# How do i write aws cli commands in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS as well as Python.

AWS CLI, the below command is working perfectly fine:

```
aws cloudformation package --template-file sam.yaml --output-template-file output-sam.yaml --s3-bucket <<bucket_Name>>
```

The goal is to create automate python script which will run the above command. I tried to google it but none of the solutions is working for me.

Below are the solution that I have tried but not able to upload the artifacts onto the S3 bucket.

test.py file:

```
import subprocess
command= ["aws","cloudformation","package","--template-file","sam.yaml","--output-template-file","output-sam.yaml","--s3-bucket","<<bucket_name>>"]
print(subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))
```

Comment: You can use the boto3 library for python.

Comment: Yep, under the hood the aws-cli leverages boto3 anyway.

Comment: Do you get any output when you run the program?

Comment: @Dmitry There is no native support for the cloudformation package functions in boto3 afaik. You'd have to implement the same logic that the awscli implements using change sets etc.

Comment: @HarshitKothari you didn't explain what is going wrong. What fails? Is there an error message?

Comment: when the script runs, nothing happens...@jarmod

Comment: @jarmod: Do you have any sample change sets script for the same?

Answer (score 4):

It can easily be done using the os library. The simplest way of doing it is given in the code.

```
import os
os.system("aws cloudformation package --template-file sam.yaml --output-template-file output-sam.yaml --s3-bucket <<bucket_name>>")
```

However, subprocess can be used for a little complicated tasks.
You can also check out boto3 library for such tasks. Boto is AWS SDK for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how this `aws-cli` command [is implemented](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/4ff0cbacbac69a21d4dd701921fe0759cf7852ed/awscli/customizations/cloudformation/package.py) as it's all in Python already. Basically `aws cloudformation package` uploads the template to S3, so you can do the same with `boto3` as mentioned in the comments.